# == statement being ignored.-Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a "guess the dice number" game, and everything seems to work except for the dice function. When I run the program I am able to input my number and it will tell me whether I lost or won. But if I do manage to guess the correct number it says this (user input comes after the ">"):

```
What number will the dice role on?
>3
loser
3
```

I guessed the right number but it still said "loser" when it should say "winner". I assume it either has something to do with the `==` or the `if` statement.

```
import random

def Func():
    A = random.randint(1,6)
    def dice(A):
        print("What number will the dice role on?")
        bet = input(">")
        if bet == A:
            print("Winner!")
            print(A)
        else:
            print("Loser")
            print(A)
    dice(A)        
    B = print("would you like to go again?")        
    def again(B):
        YN = input("Y/N-")
        if YN == "y":
            Func()
        else:
            print("Good bye!")
    again(B)             
Func()
```

Comment: Try checking the type of your input. At a glance, it looks like you might be comparing '3' to 3.

Comment: `'3' == 3` being false isn't about the statement being ignored.

Comment: You're comparing an `int` to a `str`ing. The result will always be `False`. Change `bet = input(">")` to `bet = int(input(">"))`.

Comment: Thank you Christian Dean, That fixed it, it now says winner when I guess the correct number. Thank you :D